# Scraping needs to stop when it sees a white row

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, strip

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import json
import os

jaren = [str("2012"), str("2010"), str("2006"), str("2003"),str("2002"), str("1998"), str("1994"), str("1989"), str("1986"), str("1982"), str("1981"), str("1977"), str("1972"), str("1971"), str("1967"), str("1963"), str("1959"), str("1956")]
DESIRED_COLUMNS = {1, 2, 5} #scrapes only afk, aantal & zetels
verkiezingsData = []

filename = raw_input('Enter a filename: ') or 'data.json'

#open file and open json array
with open(filename, "w") as file:
   file.write("[{")
for Jaargetal in jaren:

     #url source 
     r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.nlverkiezingen.com/TK" + Jaargetal +".html").read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
     tables = soup.find_all("table")
     for table in tables:
         header = soup.find_all("h1")[0].getText()

         #print header
         with open(filename, "a+") as file:
              file.write("\"%s\": [" % header) #header as beginning json
         trs = table.find_all("tr")[0].getText()
         del verkiezingsData[:] #clear list before adding new data


         #add the 3 columns to a list
         for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]: #22 columns top till bottom
             for index, val in enumerate(tr.find_all('td')):
                  if index in DESIRED_COLUMNS: #linkt naar desired columns bovenin
                      verkiezingsData.append(val.getText().strip())


         #json array van de 3 vallues
         for a, b, c in zip(verkiezingsData[::3],        verkiezingsData[1::3], verkiezingsData[2::3]): #link naar desired columns 1,2,5
             data2 = {'afk':a,"aantal":b, "zetels":c}

             #file writing
             with open(filename, 'a') as outfile:
                 json.dump(data2, outfile)
                    outfile.write(",")


        #open file, delete last comma and close array
        with open(filename, 'ab+') as file:
                file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
                file.truncate()
                file.write("],")

#open file, delete last comma, and close array
with open(filename, 'r+b') as file:
    file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    file.truncate()
    file.write("}]")

#open file and pretty print json data
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    prettydata = json.load(file)
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(prettydata, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I made a scraper which scrapes from [nlverkiezingen.com](http://nlverkiezingen.com/)

It scrapes Aantal/Afk/Zetels

It has a string which scrapes a lot of years.

```
jaren = [str("2012"), str("2010"), str("2006"), str("2003"),str("2002"), str("1998"), str("1994"), str("1989")]
```

It needs to begin at row 1.

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]: #22 columns top till bottom
```

But needs to end when it sees a white line/white space instead of row 22^. (every year ends on another row) How can I code this?

Or is it possible to say somewhere in the code -  about every year in the string - when it needs to stop scraping rows? for example 2010 row 22 1959 row 10

Comment: If I have understood what you want correctly, you could maybe check:
`for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]:
    if val.getText() == "":
        continue'
or return (depending if you want to go on with the next year or just exit). But in general, I believe you should split the code into functions in order to have more control of the flow.

Comment: @mkran  Should I also use the [1:22]: then? Because it still goes wrong: { "aantal": "1317", "afk": "PCNU", "zetels": "" }, { "aantal": "", "afk": "", "zetels": "" }, { "aantal": "5999531", "afk": "", "zetels": "150" },  
It only/immediately needs to stop when the first row (aantal) is "" not at zetels

Comment: I have posted a possible solution to your problem (I have tested it and it seems to do what I have understood you want, I hope it helps). As for the "Should I also use the [1:22]:", I haven't seen the site you are scraping, so I cannot say. If the table has only rows you need then maybe you don' t need to contain your solution to [1:22]. It is very specific to the site you are scraping though.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume here that you are asking that you want to break out of the `for` loop when `tr` dom is empty.

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]:
    if tr.getText() == "":
        break
```

Comment: Should I also use the [1:22]: then? Because it still goes wrong:  {
                "aantal": "1317",
                "afk": "PCNU",
                "zetels": ""
            },
            {
                "aantal": "",
                "afk": "",
                "zetels": ""
            },
            {
                "aantal": "5999531",
                "afk": "",
                "zetels": "150"
            },

Comment: It only/immediately needs to stop when the first row (aantal) is "".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop the iteration if a specific column like 'aantal' is empty then maybe try something like this:

```
    # add the 3 columns to a list
    for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]:  # 22 columns top till bottom
        td_cols = tr.find_all('td')
        if td_cols[2].getText() == '':  # second column is aantal, if empty break loop
            break
        # else go on as usual
        for index, val in enumerate(td_cols):
            # do stuff
```

However, I believe you should try structure your code differently so that you have more control over the flow.